# Besides FSharpCodeProvider (from PowerPack), what else in needed for compiling F# code on the fly?

Tags: f#, fsharpcodeprovider

I'm compiling code on the fly using the FSharpCodeProvider class coming on the PowerPack libraries. The point is that in a machine without visual studio 2010 I'm able to do that only as long as I have the F# standalone compiler installed in that machine. Does anybody know if that's the way it is supposed to be? My concern is that the standalone compiler is distributed only as CTP software not having a final release version.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can see in [the source code](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68767#684933) that `FSharpCodeProvider` calls fsc.exe. So, yes, it is dependant on the F# compiler.

The standalone F# releases are always called CTP (not sure why). In the past [it's been stated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/02/10/announcing-the-f-february-2010-release.aspx) that the code is the same as in the Visual Studio releases.